# if (isset($_POST['submit'])) not recognizing Submit button

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the echo statement to run when the submit button is pressed. I have a name for the submit button and I'm using that in the if statement but the code does not run when I press the submit button. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Week3_Landis.php -->
<!-- Jul 3, 2018 -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lab3 Landis</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border = "1">
        <form>
        <tr><td><h1>Welcome to the Diamond Maker!</h1></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Enter the size of your diamond: <input type="number" name="diamondSize"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
        </form>

        <tr><td>
        <?php
        // Row to create diamond
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            echo "stuff";
        } // End if



        ?>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't have a method set in your form tag. try <form method="post">

Comment: @Carcigenicate it's not necessary to use AJAX. Set the `target` of the form to the same page with a `post` method and the php code will run as intended.

Comment: Your form needs an action and method. See [Your first HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form)

Comment: ALL it does not need a method attribute, but the default is `method="get"` So in this case there will be no data in the `$_POST` array it will be in the `$_GET` array

Comment: @smith NO, the OP could change the code to use `$_GET` _catch 22_

Comment: @smith I would call if flexible, but whatever, certainly not worth falling out over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default submit method is `GET`  and not `POST`. Use `<form method="post">`.

Comment: `<from` - the word is "form".

Comment: *"Try"* - that should be replaced with "Use".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Done.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing one/two ideal arguments for your html form tag. Because PHP uses a server to process information, your form must go to the server and come back, thus requiring an action and a method in your starting form tag, as follows:

```
<form action="/YOUR_PAGE.php" method="post">
```

This way, when you hit submit, the form knows to send the information using the post method, and will return that same information back to the correct page.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<form>` tag does not have an `action` or a `method`. You are not `POST`ing anything.

```
<form method="POST">
```